# Add attributes to XML tags in Yii 2 Response

Tags: php, xml, yii2

Yii2. Action (method) in controller:

```
public function actionGet()
{
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_XML;

    return [
        'items' => [
            ['id' => 'data'],
            ['id' => 'body'],
        ],
    ];
}
```

At output get XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <items>
        <item>
            <id>data</id>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>body</id>
        </item>
    </items>
</response>
```

How can add attributes in XML tags? And remove `response` tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
    <item update="true">
        <id>data</id>
    </item>
    <item update="false" new="true">
        <id>body</id>
    </item>
</items>
```

Documentation not show this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

This feature is currently not supported and isn't on the roadmap. You'll have to build your own ResponseFormatter (implementing http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-responseformatterinterface.html) to achieve this.

See: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/5996

Also, removing the `response` tag isn't possible. You can rename the root tag by setting the `rootTag` value for the formatter. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-xmlresponseformatter.html#%24rootTag-detail